# Running firefox headless issues

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run Firefox headless in Selenium. My code below is:

```
selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.firefox(firefox_options = options)

driver.get('https://wtfismyip.com')
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
```

It keeps giving me:

```
 driver = webdriver.firefox(firefox_options = options)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have had no issues with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a typo mistake.

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options)
Note the capital F.

It should work now.

Comment: same issue still :|

Comment: he said Note the capital F in Firefox

Comment: @ShubhamJain It worked.  Ouch!! It uses 20% more cpu!!!  It uses less cpu to not use headless.  Chrome saved 10%

Comment: @ShubhamJain I will use FF for sure when it's out of beta.  It saddens me they did not add extension capability to headless

Comment: @ShubhamJain wc! :)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your firefox and install Nightly version as below :

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/

You can use Revo to uninstall Firefox so all registry entry will be removed

Comment: I still seem to get issues with this line - driver = webdriver.firefox(firefox_options = options).